# Prestasho upgrade backup and log file locations

Tags: prestashop, upgrade

Tried to upgrade from 1.6.0 to the latest, 1.7.3. Had to to it in 3 steps since you can't directly upgrade to the latest. The last upgrade was stuck and I got a blank page as a result.

Where does it store the backups and upgrade logs? Can't rollback in admin because of the blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backups are located in admin folder then in "backups".

You should activate debug mode first, it might just be a little bug to fix (file config/defines.inc.php), just change define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false); to define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);